# Invoking a non-getter method in Struts2 action class

Tags: struts2

In a Struts2 Action class, if I had a method named `calculate()`, which does some calculation and displays the results, how could I call this method from the JSP using Struts tags such as `<s:property value="calculate"/>` ?

If I named the method `getCalculate()`, then `<s:property value="calculate"/>` would work, but is it possible to use invoke that method with method name `calculate()`?

Comment: Would it not have been quicker to just try your own suggestion???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call use full method name like

```
<s:set var="anyName"   value='calculate()'/>
```

Common example is

```
<s:if test='String1.equals(String2)'>
     CASE
</s:if>
```